# How to set gitlab's boundle nginx to avoid the conflict with an existing nginx

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I want to use a non-bundled nginx ,I overwrite /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb set 
`nginx['enable'] = false`,then I excute the commands:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

I find that the bundled nginx is still started,and it occupy the 80 port;
I launch the existing nginx,and I get:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

after,I think another way,I can change the port of bundle nginx ,like 8088;
I overwrite /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb set:`nginx['listen_port'] = 8888`,then I reconfigure and restart gitlab;

But I find the port is not changed;I open the file '/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf',the main code like these:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
      ...
      ...
```

the bundle nginx still listen to the 80 port;

I don't know how to resolve the confilct between existing nginx and bundle nginx;any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it...because of my forgetting uncomment the code.